# Replace IntentService with ViewModel

Tags: android

In one activity when I press a button a dialog is opened. When the user click ok, an async operation must be executed and result shown to the user. At the moment an `IntentService` is used to perform the async task and it sends back the result to the activity using `LocalBroadcastManager`. I'd like to replace this model with `ViewModel`. What's the best approach in this case? What I don't like is that if the service sends data while the activity is paused the result is lost because the receiver is unregistered during onPause.